# wxPython - Create Wizard with facility to change 'Next' page based on user choice

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to create a simple installer using the wxWizard class. On the first page (page0) I would like to have 3 options

```
 1. Install (click Next goes to page install1) 
 2. Upgrade (click Next goes to page upgrade1)
 3. Remove (click Next goes to page remove1)
```

Due to my lack of experience with OOP (and programming in general), I'm unable to understand how to create the page0 object that would do this.

If I create page0 before install1: global name 'install1' is not defined
If I create install1 before page0: maximum recursion depth exceeded
If I look at class SkipNextPage at http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/wxPython/wizard/wx.wizard.html: there is a funky `GetNext()` method that also don't understand.

Please help!

```
import wx
import wx.wizard

class InstallPage_Dyn(wx.wizard.PyWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.wizard.PyWizardPage.__init__(self, parent)
        self.next = self.prev = None


class InstallPage0(wx.wizard.PyWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.wizard.PyWizardPage.__init__(self, parent)
        self.next = self.prev = None
        self.box = wx.RadioBox (self, -1, 'Choose one of the options below and hit Next\n', choices=['Install','Upgrade','Remove'], style = wx.VERTICAL | wx.EXPAND)

        # Set Next button based on user choice
        self.box.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBOX, self.SetNext(install1))

    # Setter and getter methods to specify Next and Previous buttons#     
    def SetNext(self, next):
        userchoice = self.box.GetSelection()
        if userchoice == 0: 
            self.SetNext(install1)
        elif userchoice == 1:
            self.SetNext(upgrade1)
        elif userchoice == 2:
            self.SetNext(remove1)

    def SetPrev(self, prev):
        return self.prev

    def GetNext(self):
        return self.next

    def GetPrev(self):
        return self.prev


# Define application and create the wizard
app = wx.App()

wizard = wx.wizard.Wizard(None, -1, "Installer")
wizard.SetPageSize((500,350))

# User selected install. Create the pages
install1 = InstallPage_Dyn(wizard, "Install")
upgrade1 = InstallPage_Dyn(wizard, "Upgrade")
remove1 = InstallPage_Dyn(wizard, "Remove")

# Create page instances
page0 = InstallPage0(wizard, "Installer")

wizard.RunWizard(page0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
class InstallPage_Dyn(wx.wizard.PyWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.wizard.PyWizardPage.__init__(self, parent)
        self.title = wx.StaticText(self,-1,title)
        self.title.SetFont(wx.Font(40,wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT,wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL,wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD))
        self.next = self.prev = None
    def SetPrev(self,prev):
        self.prev = prev
    def GetPrev(self):
        return self.prev

class InstallPage0(wx.wizard.PyWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent, title,optional_panels = {}):
        wx.wizard.PyWizardPage.__init__(self, parent)
        self.prev = self
        self.next = optional_panels.values()[0]
        self.box = wx.RadioBox (self, -1, 'Choose one of the options below and hit Next\n', choices=optional_panels.keys(), style = wx.VERTICAL | wx.EXPAND)
        self.opts = optional_panels.keys()
        self.pages   = optional_panels.values()
        for p in self.pages:
            p.SetPrev(self)
        self.next = self.pages[0]
        self.optional_panels = optional_panels

    def GetNext(self):
        return self.pages[self.box.GetSelection()]
    def GetPrev(self):
        return self.prev
...
page0 = InstallPage0(wizard, "Installer",{'install':install1,'upgrade':upgrade1,'remove':remove1})

wizard.RunWizard(page0)
#app.MainLoop()
```

here is the full code ... name it `wiz.py` and run it

```
import wx
import wx.wizard

class InstallPage_Dyn(wx.wizard.PyWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.wizard.PyWizardPage.__init__(self, parent)
        self._title = title
        self.title = wx.StaticText(self,-1,title)
        self.title.SetFont(wx.Font(40,wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT,wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL,wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD))
        self.next = self.prev = None
    def SetPrev(self,prev):
        self.prev = prev
    def GetPrev(self):
        return self.prev

class InstallPage0(wx.wizard.PyWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent, title,optional_panels = {}):
        wx.wizard.PyWizardPage.__init__(self, parent)
        self.prev = self
        self.next = optional_panels[0]
        options = [p._title for p in optional_panels]
        self.box = wx.RadioBox (self, -1, 'Choose one of the options below and hit Next\n', choices=options, style = wx.VERTICAL | wx.EXPAND)
        self.pages   = optional_panels
        for p in self.pages:
            p.SetPrev(self)
        self.next = install1
        self.optional_panels = optional_panels
    def SetPrev(self, prev):
        self.prev = prev
        return self.prev
    def GetNext(self):
        return self.pages[self.box.GetSelection()]
    def GetPrev(self):
        return self.prev


# Define application and create the wizard
app = wx.App(redirect=False)

wizard = wx.wizard.Wizard(None, -1, "Installer")
wizard.SetPageSize((500,350))

# User selected install. Create the pages
install1 = InstallPage_Dyn(wizard, "Install")
upgrade1 = InstallPage_Dyn(wizard, "Upgrade")
remove1 = InstallPage_Dyn(wizard, "Remove")

# Create page instances
page0 = InstallPage0(wizard, "Installer",[install1,upgrade1,remove1])

wizard.RunWizard(page0)
```

Comment: Thanks Joran. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. Page0 opens up but instead of the Next button it shows the 'Finish' button. Almost as if page0.next was never set.

Comment: what do you mean?... it should be fine i just posted the raw code from my file which runs fine for me ...what error do you get?

Comment: Ok great your full code listing works perfectly. I was trying to plug your code into my original script and must've made a mistake there. Since you have spent so much time on this can I please ask you to clarify: why does self.next = optional_panels.values()[0] which is basically a reference to install1 work in your code while it went into infinite recursion when I used self.next = install1 directly?

Comment: it doesnt for me ... if I change `self.next =self.pages[0]` to `self.next = install1` it works the same

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your excellent help. I will try to find out what was throwing me off.

Comment: Joran I already have another problem. In the list, the order of choices shows up as Upgrade, Remove, Install instead of Install, Upgrade, Remove. How to set it right? I'm running your code as is.

Comment: just set `choices=['install','upgrade','remove']` when you setup the radio ... I changed the full code to allow ordering them how you want...